# Does USGS 3DEP data use a hash or checksum?

Tags: data, dem, elevation, download, usgs

I'm downloading some [USGS 3DEP elevation data](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/?basemap=b1&category=ned,nedsrc&title=3DEP%20View), e.g., the file at the following URL:

https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/563afea8e4b0d6133fe7357b

The "ID" of this file is given in both the URL and the metadata as the 24-length string `563afea8e4b0d6133fe7357b`.

My question is, **does this ID correspond to a hash function or checksum applied to the file?** I'd like to verify the downloaded file's integrity by comparing some checksum to this ID. Both MD5 and SHA1 produce much longer hashes than 24 characters, and I'm not sure what else to try.